# Meteor.js with Iron Router buttons and forms in templates not working

Tags: javascript, forms, button, meteor, iron-router

I have a project using Meteor.js and Iron:router. Before I had any routing going on, and my application was just one page, my forms and buttons were all working just fine, but now that I have routing to multiple pages working, my forms and buttons don't seem to be "clickable." Everything that is already in the database loads and renders fine, but I now have no way to add/remove/change the data from my application.

Here is the HTML:

```
<template name="home">
  <title>Grocery List</title>
<div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menuItem">{{> loginButtons}}</li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="{{ pathFor 'home'}}" class="menuLink">Home</a> </li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="{{ pathFor 'saved'}}" class="menuLink">Saved Lists</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="{{ pathFor 'about'}}" class="menuLink">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
{{#if currentUser}}
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1 id="title">Grocery List</h1>

    <form class="new-item">
      <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type to add new items" />
    </form>
  </header>

  <ul>
    {{#each items}}
      {{> item}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Items Found</h1>
  </header>

  <ul>
    {{#each found_items}}
      {{> found}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h3>
      Tax: ${{calcTax}}
    </h3>
    <h2>
      Total: ${{priceSum}}
    </h2>
    <button class="save">Save list</button>
  </header>
</div>
{{else}}
  <div class="container">
  <h3>Please log in first.</h3>
  </div>
{{/if}}
</template>

<template name="about">
  <title>About Grocery List</title>
  <div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menuItem">{{> loginButtons}}</li>
      <li class="menuItem"><a href="{{ pathFor 'home'}}" class="menuLink">Home</a> </li>
      <li class="menuItem"><a href="{{ pathFor 'saved'}}" class="menuLink">Saved Lists</a></li>
      <li class="menuItem"><a href="{{ pathFor 'about'}}" class="menuLink">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div  class="container">
    <header><h1>About</h1></header>
    <p>This application can be used to make, save and update grocery lists. Once the user is in the store, they can use it to check off items on the list, put in the price and see the total, with tax.</p>
    <p>Users can also save their previous lists to either reuse them, or compare current prices to previous ones.</p>
    <p>Future implementations of this page would also allow the user to change the tax rate depending on their location, and include coupons and other discounts in the pricing.</p>
    <h3>
      Coding Environments
    </h3>
    <ul>
      <li>IntelliJ IDEA</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>
      Frameworks
    </h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Meteor</li>
      <li>Iron Router</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>
      Languages
    </h3>
    <ul>
      <li>HTML</li>
      <li>CSS</li>
      <li>Javascript</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="saved">
  <title>Saved Lists</title>
  {{#if currentUser}}
  <div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menuItem">{{> loginButtons}}</li>
      <li class="menuItem"><a href="{{ pathFor 'home'}}" class="menuLink">Home</a> </li>
      <li class="menuItem"><a href="{{ pathFor 'saved'}}" class="menuLink">Saved Lists</a></li>
      <li class="menuItem"><a href="{{ pathFor 'about'}}" class="menuLink">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <header><h1>Your Saved Lists</h1></header>

    <ul>
      {{#each saved_items}}
        {{> save}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
  {{else}}
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Please log in first.</h3>
    </div>
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="item">
  <li>
    <button class="found">Got it!</button>

    <input type="number" name="price" placeholder="Sale Price" />

    <span class="text">{{text}}</span>
  </li>
</template>

<template name="found">
  <li>
    <button class="remove">&times;</button>
    <span class="text">{{text}}</span>
    <span class="price">{{price}}</span>
  </li>
</template>

<template name="save">
  <li>
    <span class="text">{{text}}</span>
  </li>
</template>
```

And here is the Javascript:

```
Items = new Mongo.Collection("items");
Found_items = new Mongo.Collection("found_items");
Saved_lists = new Mongo.Collection("saved_lists");

Router.route('home', {path: '/'}); // Add this route
Router.route('about', {path: '/about'});
Router.route('saved', {path: '/saved'});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.home.helpers({
    items: function () {
      return Items.find({});
    },
    found_items: function () {
      return Found_items.find({});
    },
    saved_items: function () {
      return Saved_lists.find({});
    },
    priceSum: function(){

      var userItems = Found_items.find({
        userId: this._id
      }).fetch();

      var prices = _.pluck(userItems, "price");

      var totalTaxed = _.reduce(prices, function(sum, price){
        var total = sum + parseFloat(price);
        return total + (total * 0.04712);
      }, 0);

      return totalTaxed.toFixed(2);
    },
    calcTax: function () {
      var userItems = Found_items.find({
        userId: this._id
      }).fetch();

      var prices = _.pluck(userItems, "price");

      var tax =  _.reduce(prices, function(sum, price){
        return (sum + parseFloat(price)) * 0.04712;
      }, 0);

      return tax.toFixed(2);
    }
  });


  Template.home.events({
    "submit .new-item": function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var text = event.target.text.value;

      Items.insert({
        text: text,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        owner: Meteor.userId(),
        username: Meteor.user().username
      });

      event.target.text.value = "";
    }
  });

  Template.item.events({
    "click .found": function (event, template) {

      event.preventDefault();
      var price = template.find('[name="price"]').value;
      var text = template.find('.text').textContent;

      Items.remove(this._id);
      Found_items.insert({
        text: text,
        price: price
      });

    }
  });

  Template.home.events({
    "click .save": function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var list = Found_items.find({
        userId: this._id
      }).fetch();

      Saved_lists.insert(list);
    }
  });

  Template.found.events({
    "click .remove": function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      Found_items.remove(this._id);
    }
  });

  Accounts.ui.config({
    passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_ONLY"
  });
}
```

Comment: Is it simply the case that the events are not firing? What are the symptoms?

Comment: It's not events not firing. It's as if the browser doesn't even recognize them being there. When I hover my mouse over the text field, for example, the cursor doesn't change and when I click into it nothing happens at all. When I click on a button there is no change in the look of the button you would normally see. It's almost as if it were all one big image rather than separate elements, but when I inspect the elements with my browser, its all there in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok add a layout config first like that

```
Router.configure({layoutTemplate: 'layout'});
Router.route('home', {path: '/'}); // Add this route
Router.route('about', {path: '/about'});
Router.route('saved', {path: '/saved'});
```

in your html add

```
<template name="layout">
   {{>yield}}
</template>
```

this should solve your problem but you have some other errors in your code and in your insert to collection and you have assign a lot of helpers in wrong templates,if you want i could recreate your app and show you just ask.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I added what you put but it didn't change anything. Does the Layout template need to be anywhere in particular in the HTML? Can you think of anything else that might be the problem?

Comment: no you can add it with the rest of the templates.i copy paste your code and everything is working fine except some errors you have like you have a helper assign to home where it should be in the saved helper `saved_items: function () {return Saved_lists.find({}); }` .also you add to the collection save list nested objects which makes it harder to fetch them later.

Comment: I see what you mean about the helper functions and have taken care of that. But I still don't have it working. How can it work when you copy my code but not work on my machine? I've tried different browsers and its the same. I really don't know what could be causing this.+

Comment: Figured it out. It was something in my CSS completely unrelated. Thanks for your assistance.